# SheetJS How to create sheet from json and save it as buffer

Tags: node.js, xlsx, sheetjs

[Documentations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) seems confusing to me. How can i create a document from a array of objects, each object representing a row and save it as buffer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `write` function and pass the `WritingOptions` object to set the **type** of your workbook data.

Example:

```
const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new()
const filename = 'mySheet'
const dataSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(myJSONData)
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, dataSheet, filename.replace('/', ''))
```

and return for your controller, send it to the network, etc...

```
return XLSX.write(workbook, { type: 'buffer', bookType: 'csv' })
```